# JSON Parsing in SQL

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON arrays in sql server in a tabular form
Here's the data string

```
CREATE TABLE #JSONData
(
[gca] NVARCHAR(MAX)
,[User] INT
);
INSERT INTO #JSONData
VALUES ('
{"items":[{"i":"image1",
                 "url":"url-1",
                 "name":"Product 1",
                 "quantity":"1",
                 "sku":"112233",
                 "subtotal":"$24.99"},
                 {"i":image3",
                 "url":"url-3",
                 "name":"Product 3",
                 "quantity":"1",
                 "sku":"112255",
                 "subtotal":"$7.99"}]}
        ', 1)
```

I am using 
Microsoft SQL Server 2016

I am trying to use IS JSON function to check if its a valid JSON string - positive
but, I get null output when using JSON _VALUE function

```
SELECT [User],
       [gca], 
       ISJSON([gca]) AS [ISJSON], 
       JSON_VALUE([gca], '$.i') AS [i],
       JSON_VALUE([gca], '$.name') AS [Product],
       JSON_VALUE([gca], '$.quantity') AS [Quantity],
       JSON_VALUE ([gca], '$.subtotal') AS [subtotal],
       [User]

FROM #JSONData
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach may help you to get your expected results. Function `JSON_VALUE` extracts a scalar value from a `JSON` string. The `$.items` part of the input `JSON` is a `JSON` array, so you need to use `OPENSJSON()` with explicit schema to parse this `JSON` array as a table:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #JSONData ( 
   [gca] NVARCHAR(MAX),
   [User] INT
); 
INSERT INTO #JSONData 
VALUES 
   (N'
{"items":[{"i":"image1",
                 "url":"url-1",
                 "name":"Product 1",
                 "quantity":"1",
                 "sku":"112233",
                 "subtotal":"$24.99"},
                 {"i":"image3",
                 "url":"url-3",
                 "name":"Product 3",
                 "quantity":"1",
                 "sku":"112255",
                 "subtotal":"$7.99"}]}
        ', 1)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   j.*,
   d.[User] AS u
FROM #JSONData d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.[gca], '$.items') WITH (
   i varchar(100) '$.i',
   p varchar(50) '$.name',
   q int '$.quantity',
   s varchar(20) '$.subtotal'
) j
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------
i       p           q   s       u
---------------------------------
image1  Product 1   1   $24.99  1
image3  Product 3   1   $7.99   1
```

Comment: Hi again  @Zhorov  :),

I tried running this, I get
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

Comment: @oneThousand3 You have a small error in your JSON - `"i":image3"` should be `"i":"image3"`. The statement in the answer runs correctly. Thanks.